# como fazer uma div flutuar sobre outra div

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando fazer uma interface parecida com a do whatsapp web a qual tem um cabeçalho verde e um fundo cinza onde a caixa das conversas esta contidas sobre este fundo cinza e o cabeçalho verde. A unica maneira que consigo pensar em como isso foi feito é usando divs. Assumindo que o cabeçalho verde e fundo cinza são divs, e que a caixa contendo as conversas é outra div, como faço para essa div das conversas ficar sobreposta às outras divs?

o que tenho é isso aqui:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e o que quero eh isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qualquer elemento html pode ser flutuado, o div por si só não faz nada, então a questão não é divs, mas sim como flutuar qualquer coisa, o problema é que eu não entendi o efeito que você quer, poderia fazer um desenho ou algo assim para explicar?

Comment: editei a pergunta, pus 2 imagens lá. O quadrado laranja é uma div e o cabeçalho preto é outra!

Comment: mas você quer que a DIV laranja fique por cima de todos elementos, o que ele fique apenas um pouco em cima da div preta que esta no topo?

Comment: quero ela só um pouco por cima da parte preta, mas quero controlar o quanto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que é mais ou menos isso que você quer... (copiei alguns detalhes do web.whatsapp)

```css
.f {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}
.b {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
.w {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: calc(100% - 38px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 19px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='f'>
  <span class='b'></span>
  <div class='w'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo! Obrigado!!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar `position: relative;` com `top` negativo e o `margin: 0 auto;` para alinhar no meio a div laranja

```css
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.topo {
    background: #000;
    height: 48px;
}

.laranja {
    position: relative;
    background: #fc0;
    width: 400px; /* ajuste a largura */
    height: 500px; /* ajuste a altura */
    margin: 0 auto; /* alinha a div no centro */
    top: -35px; /*CONTROLE AQUI A DISTANCIA*/
}
```

```html
<div class="topo">

</div>

<div class="laranja">

</div>
```